# Using controller set variables in conditional .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller with an action that is being hit remotely, after which my `controller_action.js.erb` file is run.

Within my controller's action, I am setting a variable `@successful = true|false` (true|false based on the return value of a function).

Within my javascript file, I want to say `if @successful` and either alert that the action was successful or alert that it was not.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speak HAML usually, so this might not be exactly correct:

```
if(<%= @successful %>) {
  // do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

In HAML, it would be:

```
:javascript
  if(#{@successful}) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // do other stuff
  }
```

Alternatively, you could do this:

(ERB)

```
<%- if @successful %>
  // JS code if true
<%- else %>
  // JS code if false
<%- end %>
```

(HAML)

```
- if @successful
  :javascript
    // JS code if true
- else
  :javascript
    // JS code if false
```

The first option will always render all your JS code on the client side, the only difference being if `true` or `false` is in the `if` clause.

The second option will conditionally only render the JS code for the true or false case.

Comment: The correct answer lies in this response. The first code block worked perfectly. If you could remove the superfluous stuff, you've got best answer.

Comment: A lot of people use HAML instead of ERB, seems useful to leave it in. Is there something incorrect I should remove/edit, or a reason you think the HAML is superfluous?

Comment: I added ERB for the second approach, and explained the difference between the two approaches.

Comment: I just thought it was superfluous because I'm not using it. Good point–someone may find it useful. I won't verify it, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<%- if @successful %>
   alert('Blabla');
<%- else %>
   alert('Blabal');
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, raphaelcm had the right answer in there first. This is mostly right, but a little ugly since you use rails if else instead of javascript's. Does `<%-` differ from `<%=` in any significant way? I have never seen the former before.

Comment: `<%-` doesn't render any output, while `<%=` does.

Comment: I thought to not render output you just use `<%` is that synonymous with `<%-`?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't entirely correct.  `<%-` and `-%>` are like `<%` and `%>`, but also suppress leading and trailing whitespace.  See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html