# js.erb view runs all js code regardless of ruby if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using a js format from the rails controller and js.erb view to execute some html changes when a form is submitted. In this js.erb file, there are multiple ruby if statements. All partials are being retrieved (according to Chrome Network tab) regardless of the if statements being true or false. Only the correct actions are being executed in the html but these extra js actions are causing the time to be nearly 1 second vs 54 ms if I remove the if statement from the action.  I'm wondering if there is a way for the js code to only be run when the proper conditions are met. Thanks.

js.erb file

```
$("#edit_time_modal_<%= @order.id %>").modal("hide");
<% new_time = @order.order_start_date_time %>
<% if @order_date != @order.order_start_date_time %>
  <% end_of_day = Time.zone.now.end_of_day %>
  <% if @order_date < end_of_day && new_time < end_of_day %>
    $("#order_details_<%= @order.id %>").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'order_details', todays_order: @order) %>');
    $("#dashboard_orders_table").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'orders_table') %>');
    $("#dashboard_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'dashboard_totals') %>');
    $(".select_order").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'new_delivery_select_order') %>');
  <% elsif @order_date < end_of_day && new_time > end_of_day %>
    $("#dashboard_order_row_<%= @order.id %>").remove();
    $("#dashboard_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'dashboard_totals') %>');
    $("#tom_orders").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_orders') %>');
    $("#tom_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_totals') %>');
    $(".select_order").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'new_delivery_select_order') %>');
    $("#tom_orders_date").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_orders_date') %>');
  <% elsif @order_date > end_of_day && new_time < end_of_day %>
    $("#tom_order_<%= @order.id %>").remove();
    $("#tom_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_totals') %>');
    $("#dashboard_orders_table").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'orders_table') %>');
    $("#dashboard_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'dashboard_totals') %>');
    $(".select_order").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'new_delivery_select_order') %>');
    $("#tom_orders_date").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_orders_date') %>');
  <% elsif @order_date > end_of_day && new_time > end_of_day %>
    $("#tom_orders").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_orders') %>');
    $("#tom_totals").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_totals') %>');
    $("#tom_orders_date").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'tom_orders_date') %>');
  <% end %>
<% end %>

$("#edit_time_modal_<%= @order.id %>").replaceWith('<%= j(render 'edit_time', order: @order) %>');
```

Controller action

```
def update_order_time
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    if params[:extras].present?
      @order.update_attributes(...)
    else
      @order.update_attributes(...)
    end
    @order_date = params[:order_date]
    if Order.tomorrows_orders.present?
      @tomorrows_orders = Order.tomorrows_orders.order(:order_start_date_time)
    elsif Order.day_after_tom_orders.present?
      @tomorrows_orders = Order.day_after_tom_orders.order(:order_start_date_time)
    elsif Order.three_days_orders.present?
      @tomorrows_orders = Order.three_days_orders.order(:order_start_date_time)
    elsif Order.four_days_orders.present?
      @tomorrows_orders = Order.four_days_orders.order(:order_start_date_time)
    else
      @tomorrows_orders = []
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419705/using-controller-set-variables-in-conditional-js-erb-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(<%= @order_date == @order.order_start_date_time %>) {
  // do something ...
} else {
  // do something different ...
}
```

The above code will run all code on client-side regardless of if statement outcome (i.e. both the do something and do something different)

```
<% if @order_date != @order.order_start_date_time %>
  // do this only
<% else %>
  // do that only
<% end %>
```

This will only run 1 set of code based on the if statement (i.e. only "do this only" or "do that only")